# Finding broken parenthesis?

Tags: parsing, intellisense

Is there an efficient algorithm for finding broken parenthesis in a block of text for the purpose of intellisense error highlighting?

For instance:

```
function f() {
    var a = [1, 2, 3];
    if ((a[1] < 1) || (a[0] > 2)) {
        console.log((a + 5).toString());
    }
}
```

Where any `(`, `)`, `[`, `]`, `{`, or `}` character might be dropped or adding in correctly and the correct issue might be highlighted, for instance spotting the specific statement, function, conditional, etc level item causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is not difficult:

- Have a stack of characters
- For each character in the code:

  - If it's an opening bracket, push it onto the stack
  - If it's a closing bracket, pop one char from the stack, both must match
- At the end the stack must be empty

Then you could maybe highlight the unmatched bracket(s).

Comment: That wouldn't satisfy the question as you might have something missing and something added in different spots which would throw it off.

Comment: @CoryG Do you have an example?

Comment: Just take any piece of code several pages long and add/drop parenthesis into it, visual studio has reasonable detection though still not perfect as sometimes you can adjust the number of parenthesis within a single function to cause the entire page to show up as having an error - I'm thinking it might need to be context-specific breaking searches on new functions or similar but for things like JavaScript even that isn't ideal.

Comment: You don't have to highlight the entire page, just the two unmatching brackets. I don't know of any IDE that does it better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that one way of approaching your problem is to validate the matching bracket groups. This may be achieved using the regular expression - see: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-match-nested of  Steven Levithan.